# CS50 - DNA Assignment in Python

Tags: python, cs50

I'm kinda stuck on DNA cs50's pset , how can I load the text into a variable, get the headers from the first row and start counting
this is my code so far:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    csv_list = list(csv_reader)

STR = 
for STR in csv_list[0][1:]:
    if 'AGAT' in csv_list[STR]:
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you stuck on? To load the headers into a variable, you can use `STR = csv_list[0][1:]` so that you have a list of the patterns.

You can then use this list variable to do your comparisons (I recommend using regular expressions to just get more comfortable with it).

Answer (score 0):

You can write

variable = open('file_path', 'r')

variable = variable.read()

Comment: The read() method reads the whole file, of it is not specified in the argument how many characters you want to return, e.g. read(5) for first 5 characters. The user was asking how to read everything without reading the header, and if you choose this approach, you can then use readLine() method to read the first line which is a header.